# Which of the following groups are isomorphic? Choose from 4.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, products, group-isomorphism

I just started group theory revision and this is my first question. I can only think that the classification of finite groups may help me, but I cannot think how. Any guidance or an answer to set me on my way would be appreciated. Kindest regards!

Which of the following groups are isomorphic? Explain your answer.

i) $C_{12} \times C_{15} \times C_{7}$

ii) $C_{14} \times C_{30} \times \langle(1,2,3)\rangle$

iii) $\mathbb{Z}_{28} \times C_{3} \times C_{5} \times \langle(1,3,2)\rangle$

iv) $C_{14} \times C_{6} \times \mathbb{Z}_{15}$

Comment: Is $\Bbb Z_{28}=\Bbb Z/28\Bbb Z =C_{28}$?

Comment: Try to split up the cyclic groups into their 'counterparts', for instance: $C_{14} \cong C_2 \times C_7$ (which can't be split further, because 2 and 7 are primes).

Comment: If I show that when I split them up into cyclic parts, they are essentially the same - will that do the trick? Does that show that they are isomorphic to each other. What do I do about <(1,3,2)> etc?

Comment: I agree with @ArnaudD.  that you might want to make your notations consistent first.

Comment: @CatherineDrysdale Is this how the question appears in your book (or wherever it's from)? The different notations look weird, but maybe part of the exercise is to realize that all of these are cyclic groups.

Comment: This is how it appears in the book. As the groups are abelian are all isomorphic to $C_2, \times C_2 \times C_3 \times C_3 \times C_5 \times C_7$. I take it that this means they are all isomorphic to each other which answers the question?

Comment: @CatherineDrysdale Yes, since isomorphism of groups is an equivalence relation. Thus if $G \cong H$ and $H \cong K$, then $G \cong K$.